# How to find number of milliseconds that have elapsed from a timestamp in local/any timezone in java

Tags: java, date, calendar, timezone

I know that System.currentTimeMillis() gives the number of milliseconds that have elapsed from epoch(1 Jan 1970, 00:00:00 GMT). But I need a solution to find the number of milliseconds that have elapsed from say 1 Jan 1970, 00:00:00 IST or any other timezone in general.

Comment: May I ask why you want to do this?

Comment: Becoz i need this value in my application to perform some other checks

Comment: It just seems like a very strange thing to want to do.  The number of milliseconds since the epoch is a standard way of measuring a point in time irrespective of time zone.  Using a different epoch could be very confusing to someone looking at your code.

Comment: Yeah, i understand your point @SimonC. I will think of a different way to solve my problem

Answer (score 1):

Convert the `Calendar` to the IST timezone and compare the values by calling `Calendar.getTimeInMillis();`

Please go through the below link for converting to TimeZones.[TimeZone Conversion](http://www.kodejava.org/examples/200.html)

Comment: Calendar.getTime() will give the local time irrespective of whether we change the Calendar to a different timezone or not. Thats my observation. Pls re check and correct me if im wrong

Comment: I mean to say, it is getTimeInMillis().In general there is no API to compare Date as far as I know.But anyways, I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is a way to get the time for a specific zone:

```
DateTimeZone tz = DateTimeZone.forID("America/Winnipeg");
DateTime dt = new DateTime(tz);
DateFormat df = DateFormat.getDateInstance();
df.format(dt.getTime());
```

The IDs can be found on this [site](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/timezones.html).

Comment: I am looking how to find the no. of milliseconds that have elapsed from this new timestamp. Not how to convert to a different timezone